# What is SCNLookAtConstraint doing behind the scenes?

Tags: ios, swift, vector, scenekit

What is the math that SCNLookAtConstraint is doing? I want to try to recreate this with vectors.

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be done with a cross product and a dot product once you have the two directional vectors.

---

By default the node points in the direction of the negative z-axis of its local coordinate system.

The other direction we are interested in is from the node that looks to the other node, in the node that looks's local coordinate system. You can get it by converting the positions using `convertPosition:fromNode:` or 
`convertPosition:toNode:`.

If not done already, normalize the two directional vectors.

With the two directions in the local coordinate system, a cross product between the two gives a vector that is orthogonal to the plane that can be formed between the two directions. This vector is the surface normal to that plane. Any rotation around that normal is going to be another vector that remains in the plane.

Since the two directions are normalized, a dot product of the two should give you `cos(ϴ)`, where ϴ is the angle between the two.

Rotating the first vector (the one that points in the direction of the negative z-axis) by this angle around the normal to the plane should make it point in the same direction as the second vector (that one that points at the other node).

That should be the way it's done for two vectors (or at least one way to do it).

To do it for a node, you would set a rotation of that angle around that axis, to the node that is looking. This would rotate the node so that it's local negative z-axis (the direction it's looking) would point at the other node.

---

I have a very similar example in one of the chapters for [3D Graphics with Scene Kit](http://scenekitbook.com), where a node is rotated to point straight out of the surface of a sphere. You can look at the [sample code](https://github.com/d-ronnqvist/SCNBook-code/blob/master/Chapter%2005%20-%20Earth/Code/Chapter%2005%20-%20Earth/EarthView.m#L217) to see how it's solved there.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? The OP is trying to recreate the look-at constraint effect with vector math, and this answer shows one way of doing so (including linking to sample code). I don't see why this answer would be "not useful".

Comment: Again, the question is what math the constraint is doing and how to recreate it with vectors. This answer shows how to do it using linear algebra and vectors.